# Ajax method starts returning 302 all of the sudden

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app and there is an ajax method in it. Previously it returns 200 and result. Now it starts returning 302 and result as which is **still correct** (I can see that in Google Chrome debug console).

Here is the xaml code:

```
    :javascript
        $(document).ready(function() { 
            $(document).on("click", "#my_id", function(){
              $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/my_url",
                success: function(data){
                  window.location = data;
                }
            });
          });
        });


   def my_url
    #getting a data.....
    #returning the data... there is nothing unusual
  end
```

**UPDATE**:
That's what I did:

```
  def my_url
    result = get_result()
    response.headers['Location'] = request.referer
    result
  end
```

but `Location` header in `Response` has not been changed and the error is remaining.

Comment: What is the value of the Location header in the response? Maybe some middleware is redirecting for authorization.

Comment: @Cixate, that's right, location in the response in equal to the url I want to redirect the user. if that's the problem, what should I do?

Comment: @AlanDert "that's right, location in the response in equal to the url I want to redirect the user" - _why_ are you wanting to redirect them? The original code says that the 302 is a _problem_ and yet you're saying you _want_ to redirect them. Now you've given an update where you change the `Location` header… what is ***actually*** going on here?

Comment: 302 is not an error, it's the status code that tells the browser that you are trying to redirect the user to some other Location. Adding the Location header automatically sets the status code to 302.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

302 is not an error code. It's the HTTP status code for a redirect which you are doing by adding a `Location` header. Adding the `Location` header automatically changes the status code to 302. The only type of expected response for a 302 is something that a browser that doesn't understand a 302 will see. For example, an HTML page explaining that it is a redirect with a link to the new page. For AJAX no response is expected for a 302 and the browser will fetch the results of the new location you are redirecting to.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3 for more details about HTTP status codes.